# combinatorics problem counting

Tags: combinatorics

We are given a word which has 50 symbols and we are given an alphabet with 30 symbols each one diffrent from the others.The number of the diffrent words in which every symbol is at least one?

my idea: first we find all binom(50+30-1,30-1) then since sum is 50 if each element is in the form a >= b+1 then all b's >=0 and sum is 20 now we calculate binom(20+30-1,30-1) .Ofcourse i am using the switching method

hence answer is first binom-second?

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you are after. Is it the number of $50$-letter words where each of the $30$ letters occurs at least once?

Comment: I think you have confused yourself.  $\binom{20+30-1}{30-1}$ would answer the question "in how many ways can we make a word where the letters appear *in alphabetical order* if each letter appears at least once."  Although an interesting question, it is not related to the current problem.  Since letters can appear in any order and we consider the word $abba\dots$ to be different than $abab\dots$, I would recommend pursuing this as an Inclusion-Exclusion type problem.

Comment: No alphabet order is given

Comment: True, my point being however, that it counts combinations, not permutations.  Order is important.  In the case that there is no "official" alphabetical order, since there are a finite number of letters one can be chosen arbitrarily.

Comment: so is this correct?

Comment: okey then no problem write it :P

Answer (score 1):

The generalized [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) states that for properties $P_i$ and universal set $X$:

$$|P_1 \cap P_2 \cap \dots \cap P_n| = |X| - \sum_{i=1}^n |P_i^c| + \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=i+1}^n|P_i^c\cap P_j^c| - \dots \\
\dots \pm \sum_{i=1}^n\cdots\sum_{z=y+1}^n |P_i^c\cap\cdots\cap P_n^c|$$

That is to say, take the total number with no restriction and subtract the number that contradict each condition individually, then add back the number which contradict two at a time, subtract again the number which contradict 3 at a time, add those that... until finally you either add or subtract the number which contradict all simultaneously.

Let $P_i$ represent the property that there exists at least one of the $i$th letters in the word.

$30^{50}$ is the number of 50 letter words that exist with no restriction whatsoever.

If a single specific $P_i$ is contradicted, regardless which letter it was, there will be $29^{50}$ possible words without that letter.  There are 30 possible letters, so our current running total is $30^{50} - 30\cdot 29^{50}$

If two are contradicted, then regardless which two, there are $28^{50}$ possible words leaving both letters out simultaneously.  There are $\binom{30}{2}$ number of ways to select which two letters are missing.  So, our current running total is $30^{50} - 30\cdot 29^{50} + \binom{30}{2}\cdot 28^{50}$

...

Continuing in this fashion, we will get the following formula:

$\sum_{i=0}^{30} (-1)^i \binom{30}{i}\cdot (30-i)^{50}$

I don't expect this simplifies further easily.

---

note, if all 30 letters don't appear, in otherwords, if all 30 properties are contradicted simultaneously, there don't exist any words.  Checking the above formula to make sure that it makes sense for this potentially breaking case, it works out since $\binom{30}{30}(30-30)^{50} = 1\cdot 0^{50} = 0$

---

Note, $\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=i+1}^n\sum_{k=j+1}^n 1 = \binom{n}{3}$.  In general if there are $r$ nested summations, with each ranging from 1 higher than the previous index up to $n$, it will be $\binom{n}{r}$

Answer (score 0):

What will be the answer if we have again 100 symbol word and we need to have at least 10 symbols

also what will be the answer if these 30 symbols have alphabetical order and all words are diffrent

Comment: and each of these 10 symbols is at least one time in the word

Comment: If you mean to say, there is still a 30 symbol alphabet and we want our 100letter word to have at least 10 different letters appearing, use the generalized formula I wrote earlier, however instead of ranging up to all 30 possible contradictions, you stop at 10 contradictions.  If you mean to say there is now a 10 letter alphabet, then it will be almost exactly the same formula as before, replace everywhere you see 30 by 10, and everywhere you see 50 by 100.

Comment: I ment the first

Comment: And what if we have 100 symbol word ,30 symbol alphabet and we want to find all diffrent words in which every symbol from the 30 symbol alphabet is at least once

Comment: The method I used above will work for however long of a word in whatever size alphabet you like.  Try to read/understand the approach and why it works for the specific example before, and then generalize that approach to further variations.